# Why toString() is not working in ng-model attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, attributes, angularjs-ng-model

### How to use toString() on ng-model attribute in `angularjs`

My controller have a `array` variable

like

```
$scope.UserNameList = ['a','b','c'];
```

I want to bind this **array to string**

---

*I have tried this below code which is working*:-

```
$scope.UserNameList.toString();//result is a,b,c
```

but when i use `toString()` in `ng-model` attribute, it's not working

```
<td style="text-align: center"><label ng-model="UserNameList.toString()"></label></td>// Does not working
```

But if i use `{{ListOfRoleName.toString()}}`, then it's working.

```
<td style="text-align: center">{{ListOfRoleName.toString()}}</td>//Working
```

> Why `toString()` is not working in `ng-model` attribute?

Comment: Probably because `toString` is a javascript method and not something you can use in the HTML, even if that HTML is somewhat parsed by Angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-model` is used for two-way databinding and you can't reasonably bind to the result of a function call.

If you just want to display the result, use `ng-bind` instead.